# Print out indexes of same values in file/list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a textfile with data. For example, I want to print out all the values for "animal". So when "animal" is choosen, it will print out "Monkey", "Elephant" and "Dog". It works somewhat, but it only prints out the first value. For example if I choose "animal", it only print out Monkey.

Is there a way to make it print out all of them? Maybe there is better ways to do it?

Data2.txt:

```
Adidas, shoe
Monkey, animal
Soup, food
Elephant, animal
Dog, animal 
Taco, food
```

---

```
file = open('data2.txt')
data = file.readlines

stuffs = []
types = []


for line in data():
 line = line.strip()
 stuff, type = line.split(', ')
 stuffs.append(stuff)
 types.append(type)

animals = types.index('animal')
print (stuffs[animals])
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What does it do, and how is that different from what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you populate your lists, you have one list with animals, and one with the corresponding types, in the same position. Using `index`, you will only get the first match, but you need all.

One way would be to use `zip` to iterate pairs of animals and types, and print each animal where the type is correct.

```
for s, t in zip(stuffs, types):
    if t == "animal":
         print(s)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension to collect all the animals in a list:

```
>>> [s for s, t in zip(stuffs, types) if t == "animal"]
['Monkey', 'Elephant', 'Dog']
```

Or, change the way you store your data. For example, instead of having two lists with corresponding indices and zipping those lists back to one list of pairs, you could create a list of pairs to start with:

```
pairs = []
for line in data():
    line = line.strip()
    pairs.append(line.split(', '))

print([s for s, t in pairs if t == "animal"])
```

Or even use a dictionary, mapping types to stuffs, as suggested in some of the other answers.

Comment: Thanks! The first one was really easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through types because types.index('animal') will only return you the first one.  Once you find the index, you can find the corresponding index in stuffs.  Try this:

```
i = 0
for type in types:
  if (type == 'animal'):
    print (stuffs[i])
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: How about `for i, type in enumerate(types):`?

Comment: @ergonaut, you are more reinventing the wheel

Comment: Okay sure, but it's clear the OP needs assistance with understanding loops.  No need to complicate things with all that fancy stuff.  shrinking code only comes after you understand the fully expanded version.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better idea would be to use a dict:

```
file = open('data2.txt')
data = file.readlines

categories = {}

for line in data():
 line = line.strip()
 stuff, type = line.split(', ')
 categories.setdefault(type, []).append(stuff)

print (categories['animal'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the types and the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse your file:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
with open("test.txt") as f:
    # create rows splitting on commas 
    r = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    # create dict to store all the types
    d = defaultdict(list)
    # v = row[0], k = row[1]
    for v,k in r:
        d[k].append(v)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'shoe': ['Adidas'], 
                           'food': ['Soup', 'Taco'], 
                           'animal': ['Monkey', 'Elephant', 'Dog']})
```

Then just lookup by key:

```
print(d["animal"])
print(d["shoe"])

['Monkey', 'Elephant']
['Adidas']
```

You don't ever need to call readlines unless you actually want a list, you could have iterated over the file object or simply passed it to the csv module and iterate over the reader object as in the code above.

Comment: For some reason, `animal` appears twice in your dict. Probably a stray space in the data file... guess the `csv.reader` does not `strip` the lines

Comment: @tobias_k, you are right, that is weird as the `skipinitialspace=True` should have removed the leading space.  I will have to do a bit of investigation

Comment: But it's a trailing space, not a leading space. ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k, lol, yep it was my own doing anyway, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
with open('data','r' ) as f:
    for line in f:
       le, r = line.split(',')
       d.setdefault(r.strip(),[]).append(le.strip())

for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)

shoe ['Adidas']
food ['Soup', 'Taco']
animal ['Monkey', 'Elephant', 'Dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy this way:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("myFile")

#Then it's simple!

a[a[:,1] == 'animal'][0]
```

Comment: it wasn't me but you're assuming they know what numpy is, and what that cryptic line is doing.